# Caracteres mínimos EditText

Tags: android, edittext

Estoy intentado poner un `EditText` que establezca un mínimo de 6 caracteres y un máximo de 7. Pero, no he dado con el mínimo.

He probado lo siguiente en la actividad:

```
edPatente.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {//esto no funciona
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if(arg0.length()>6){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La cantidad mínima de caracteres para la patente es de 6 (seis) y la máxima es de 7 (siete).",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
});
}
```

Y en el layout configuré el máximo:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edPatente"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:hint="Patente"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edKilometro"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:maxLength="7"/>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> un edittext que establezca un mínimo de 6 caracteres y un máximo de 7

La validación dentro de `onTextChanged()` sería:

```
if(arg0.length()<6 || arg0.length()>7){
```

por lo tanto se tendría que realizar esta validación para obtener el resultado deseado:

```
edPatente.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                if(arg0.length()<6 || arg0.length()>7){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La cantidad mínima de caracteres para la patente es de 6 (seis) y la máxima es de 7 (siete).",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
        });
```

Comment: jajjaja gracias, estaba poniendo los <> al revés. Me ha servido, gracias

Comment: No te preocupes a todos nos sucede que tenemos un pequeño detalle, saludos @FranqoBalsamo